# How to check Availability of Region Monitoring status in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

In my app, when it loads the current position of the user, it works correctly.

But when the user goes outside of the boundaries of a city (or any specific place), I want to do something.

For that, I am reading the reference of the Apple documentation **Region Monitoring and iBeacon**
But I do not understand lots of things. Like how to determine the availability of Region Monitoring? From where i can get UUID string..?

```
- (void)registerRegionWithCircularOverlay:(MKCircle*)overlay andIdentifier:  (NSString*)identifier {
    // If the overlay's radius is too large, registration fails automatically,
    // so clamp the radius to the max value.
    CLLocationDistance radius = overlay.radius;
    if (radius > self.locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance) {
        radius = self.locManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
    }

    // Create the geographic region to be monitored.
    CLCircularRegion *geoRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]
    initWithCenter:overlay.coordinate
    radius:radius
    identifier:identifier];
    [self.locManager startMonitoringForRegion:geoRegion];
}
```

Comment: Every bluetooth device is having a UUID which you will get while monitoring.More than one device can have same UUID so when you create region it will ask for uuid for monitoring all devices of same that UUID.

Comment: john kumar - thanks for prompt..I have some issue with the following code..have u read apple documentation for this problem? i have read it ..but i did not get lot of    stuff..   i have attached link please look at this link.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: You have to understand first how works a beacon, and its limitation before anything. Here is an explaination (simple) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870219/sdks-and-beacon-bluetooth-le-development/21877010#21877010, and you may then go then to learn more.

Comment: 1)  how to check whether device support Region Monitoring or not...                                     2)  Creating and registering a geographical region based on a Map Kit overlay 3) To check whether the user is already inside the boundary of a region then prompt  4) Handling Boundary-Crossing Events for a Geographical Region with following methods - (a) locationManager:didEnterRegion:
(b) locationManager:didExitRegion:

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking into CLCircularRegion, not CLBeaconRegion

Comment: paulw11 - can you please tell me difference between CLCircularRegion and CLBeaconRegion and which delegate methods for those classes.